# Rotating image using classes

Tags: c++, image, visual-studio-2010, class, rotation

I'm having trouble rotating an image 90 degrees, the images are 768 x 768 pixels. The code I have shown here is able to create a new image, but the function I've written isn't manipulating it at all. My image class and function that's in the driver to rotate it is below. I have to rotate all the pictures 90 degrees clockwise and counterclockwise; I think my issue is trying to get the pointers to correctly switch the pixels around.

```
class image {
    public:
        image();            //the image constructor (initializes everything)
        image(string filename);  //a image constructor that directly loads an image from disk
        image(image &other); //copy constructor
        ~image();           //the image destructor  (deletes the dynamically created pixel array)
        pixel** getPixels();                    //return the 2-dimensional pixels array
        int getWidth();                     //return the width of the image
        int getHeight();                    //return the height of the image
        void createNewImage(int width, int height);

    private:
        pixel** pixels;             // pixel data array for image 
        int width, height;      // stores the image dimensions 

        void pixelsToCImage(CImage* myImage);
};

void RotateClockWise(image *imageIn)
{
     image rotateImg;
     image *ptr = (image*) &rotateImg;
     *ptr = *imageIn;
     int height = rotateImg.getHeight();
     int width = rotateImg.getWidth();
     pixel** rotatePix = rotateImg.getPixels();

     for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
         {
             rotatePix[i][j] = rotatePix[j][i];
             *(ptr + j * height + (height - i - 1)) = *(ptr + i * width + j);
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your code is very c style. This is cool, I love this kind of coding, but you can make your life easier with references.

Solution for your code:
You never set point to imageIn, just the copy the value from image in to rotateImg:

```
 image rotateImg;
 image *ptr = (image*) &rotateImg;
 *ptr = *imageIn;
```

This means you just modify the local variable rotateImg and not the object which is given by the pointer.

And here just a plain NO:
      ptr points on an image. Each +j means "go to the next image" or more precissly: ptr = ptr + sizeof(image); which should be around 12 bytes + vtable. Dont do this. You You can just do this when you loop over an 1 dimensional pixel array.

```
*(ptr + j * height + (height - i - 1)) = *(ptr + i * width + j); //BAD
```

Here is some C style code which solves the problem. I did not know you could give a 2 dimensional array via a double pointer **ptr (indirect pointers).

```
void RotateClockWise(image* imageIn)
{
     image rotateImg;
     rotateImg = *imageIn;
     image *ptr = imageIn;
     int height = rotateImg.getHeight();
     int width = imageIn->getWidth();

     pixel** normalPix = rotateImg.getPixels();
     pixel** rotatePix = imageIn->getPixels();

     for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
         {
             rotatePix[i][j] = normalPix[(height-1)-j][(width-1)-i];
         }
     }
}
```

I am to lazy to code it in C++ Style, but have a look at the Reference

```
void RotateClockWise(image& imageIn)
```

Comment: I tried this out, it should be the right code,. This makes so much more sense, but my program is breaking around a function my teacher wrote that we're not supposed to edit. There's not too much I can do about that right now. Thank you for making this much more clear though.

Comment: No problem, helping is fun and other people helped me too^^

Answer (score 1):

You have `imageIn` argument that probably points to image you want to rotate. However, you create `rotateImg` object, get pointer to this object (`ptr`) and duplicate `imageIn` to this `ptr`. So, now you manipulate image copy instead of image itself, that is why object pointed by `imageIn` never changes its value.

Comment: So you're saying I should get rid of rotateImg and use the imageIn pointer? When I try to use the getHeight() and getWidth() functions, those assignment statements no longer work.

Comment: Well, multiple changes are required in this code to force it to work; I just say you why `imageIn` never changes its pixels.